# Trying to make my bot delete message after 7 hours

Tags: discord.js

I'm making my bot trying to delete messages if they are 7 hours past their `.createdTimestamp` in a certain channel that isn't that busy, but I don't get how I could make this work in discord.js v12.2.0

Comment: Hi Frankie, and welcome to Stackoverflow! It looks like your question could use some help. You are more likely to get an answer if you follow these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`.createdTimestamp` would be hard to use, messages' timestamps are the snowflake datatype, which is hard to convert and work with see [this](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference#convert-snowflake-to-datetime). There is a much more simple solution:

Upon sending a message, set a timeout of 7 hours in milliseconds to the delete function:

```
  msg.channel.send("message to be deleted").then(msg => {
    msg.delete({timeout: 25200000})
  })
    .catch("something went wrong");
  }
```

Comment: What if the bot restarts?

Comment: If i were you, i would add every id and creation time of a message sent by the bot to a .json file, and in the bot, check every few seconds in `setInterval(function, 10000)` if the time now is atleast 7 hours later than any of the recorded times, and delete that message by it's recorded id.